# How promises behave after encountered with resolve method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am taking [this free course](https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898) that about JavaScript Promises. In lesson 7, [here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikoar93RWe4), there is 
a code snippet :

```
new Promise(function(resolve) {
  console.log('first');
  resolve();
  console.log('second');
}).then(function() {
  console.log('third');
});
```

When I run this code in console it returns:

->first

->second

->third

As far as I know, when we call the **resolve**, the **then** method should be run at that moment. So I expect:

->first

->third

So as far as I know, when we call the **resolve** it should jump to the **then** method and "`console.log("second")`" statement shouldn't have been executed.

*Can somebody explain how promises behave after encountered with resolve method?*

Comment: `As far as I know` - you're wrong .- refer to the documentation for [promise then method](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method) - also, `resolve` isn't `return` - so regardless of anything else, the `second` console.log will of course occur

Comment: "resolve, the then method should be run at that moment." - that's simply not true, in the sense of the `then` handler being executed. `then` will **always** at least wait until the current execution stack is empty, before executing the handler. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value)

Comment: Thanks  ASDFGerte, as far as I understand "calling resolve" is only indicate that "then method argument" will be executed after the last statement in constructor, if there is no any execution error in promise constructor.

Comment: What i think actually happens is, that not even `then` is run before the console log of "second". `resolve` will only change the promise to a resolved state, and enqueue potential follow ups (none at this point). Afterwards, `then` is called on the already resolved promise, but will still wait until the current execution stack is empty, before executing the handler.